# C++ : Using a static member function within class

Tags: c++, function, class, static, member

I have to make a class in which, in the constructor, I validate the arguments before creating the instance.

For that I want to make a static member function in the class, which can be used later to validate user input (that's why it needs to be static).

So it looks a bit like this:

```
//.h
...
public:
    Constructor(const int thing);
    static bool validateThing(int &thing);
...

//.cpp
Class::Constructor (const int &thing):
m_thing = thing;
{
    PRECONDITION(validateThing(thing));
    // the PRECONDITION macro refers to a homemade function that throws an error
    // if the bool in argument is false
}
...

// Later on, in the main file
...
cout << "Enter the thing" << endl;
int thing;
cin >> thing;

cout << "This thing is ";
if (!Class::validateThing(thing))
{
    cout << "not ";
}
cout << "valid." << endl;
...
```

When I try to build the class, I get the following error message:

```
no matching function for call to 'Class::validateThing(int &thing)'
```

What should I understand to make this work?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're passing a `const int` to a function that requires a *non-const* `int` *reference* in your PRECONDITION parameter ? And you may want to specify WHERE an error is reported while posting what the error says (which is more than most people do, so at least you have that going for you).

Comment: @WhozCraig: for the const int, I ended up doing what rzymek said so all the parameters involved are const. As for specifying where the error is reported, I'll keep that in mind for future questions. Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes:

```
//.h
public:
    Constructor(int thing);
    static bool validateThing(int thing);

//.cpp
Class::Constructor(int thing): m_thing(thing)
{
    PRECONDITION(validateThing(thing));
    //etc.
}

bool Class::validateThing(int thing)
{
    //implement here
}
```

It appears you did not provide an implementation of `validateThing`. You should also make sure declarations and definitions agree on types of parameters (`const`/non-`const`, references etc.) and initialize members correctly.

Functions like the constructor and `validateThing` should take `const&` arguments. But for simple types like `int` you can also pass by value.

Comment: Great, thanks! From what I get, I was trying to pass an argument by reference, which was harmful (and useless) since I didn't intend on modifying the argument anyway, right?
As for the implementation of validateThing, I did it but I figured it was useless to provide it in this example (I was implementing its instructions all over the place manually, so I know they worked).

Comment: @Chloro Exactly. But as I say in the edit, you can also pass by value for small types.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of remove `const` specifier as suggested by @iavr, just add `const` in the spec of `validateThing` function, like this:

```
//.h
...
public:
    Constructor(const int thing);
    static bool validateThing(const int &thing);
...
```

And don't forget to implement the `validateThing` function.

IMO exhaustive use of `const` specifier is a good design. It's good to know and often very important that some function does not change its argument. It's useful when we using Design by Contract and we have to care about internal and permissible class states.

Comment: Alright, I'll consider adding const in the parameter. Thanks!